# Page load slow with fontawesome icons in Angular 10

Tags: html, angular, font-awesome, angular10, page-load-time

I have an angular 10 project. One of the pages uses fontawesome icon which has over 1000 records. With these icons, the page load is very slow. I tried removing icons and the page is faster.

I'm using fontawesome-free": "^5.15.1".

Does anyone have any suggestions to overcome this issue in Angular 10?

Below is the part of the page and it has a down-arrow icon. That is the issue. If I replace this icon with a character like #, the page load is very fast. I have over 1000 rows.

[image: Page Screenshot]

Here is the ngFor generating the HTML.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let mjob of mst.jobs; index as y">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="p-0 nowrap">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <a role="button" id="btnDropdownDemo"
             class="font-weight-bold"
             data-toggle="dropdown"
             aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"
             title="{{mjob.jobStatus}}"
             [style.color]="mjob.jobStatusColor">
            <i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-down"></i>
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left font-size-8pt p-1">
            <div class="dropdown-item d-flex justify-content-around" *ngIf="mjob.tripTypeId == manifestItemRefType.PickupJob || mjob.tripTypeId == manifestItemRefType.DelJob">
              <a role="button" class="font-size-11pt"
                 (click)="onConnotePrintClick(mjob.jobId)" title="Print Connote">
                <i class="far fa-file-powerpoint"></i>
              </a>
              <a role="button" class="font-size-11pt"
                 (click)="onConnoteLabelPrintClick(mjob.jobId)" title="Print Label">
                <i class="fas fa-tag"></i>
              </a>
              <a role="button" class="font-size-11pt"
                 (click)="onCorrespondencePopupOpen(mjob.jobId,mjob.jobReference)" title="Correspondence"
                 *ngIf="helper.right(userFunctionRights.jobs_Connote_Edit)">
                <i class="far fa-comment-dots"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="p-0 nowrap">
        <span style="color: #B23CFD;">&nbsp;</span>
        <span title="{{getTripTypeStrV2(mjob.tripTypeId)}}" style="cursor:default;">{{getTripTypeStr(mjob.tripTypeId)}}</span>
        <span style="color: #B23CFD;">&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span>
        <span>{{mjob.jobReference}}</span>
        <span style="color: #B23CFD;">&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span>
        <span title="Pick-up Date">{{mjob.plannedPudateTime | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</span>
        <span style="color: #B23CFD;">&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span>
        <span title="Receiver Name">{{mjob.receiverName}}</span>
        <span style="color: #B23CFD;">&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span>
        <span title="Receiver Town">{{mjob.receiverTownName}}</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</ng-container>
```

The issue is with the below line. when I remove it, the page load is fatter.

`<i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-down"></i>`

Font awesome is added to package.json file

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1002.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~10.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.1",
```

below is the screenshot of the Network tab. I hope Font Awesome file is the "fa-solid-900.3ceb50e7bcafb577367c.woff2" which is in disk cache.

[image]

//EDIT - 16/06/2022

I have removed all Font Awesome icons and changed the HTML as below. Now it is much faster. But still, I want to keep the icon which makes look nice. With this tryout, it is clear the issue is with icon loading.

````
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="p-0 nowrap">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <a role="button" id="btnDropdownDemo"
             class="font-weight-bold"
             data-toggle="dropdown"
             aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"
             title="{{mjob.jobStatus}}"
             [style.color]="mjob.jobStatusColor">            
            <span class="badge" [style.background-color]="mjob.jobStatusColor">#</span>
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left font-size-8pt p-1">           
            <a role="button"
               (click)="onJobPopupOpen(jobPropertyModalPopup,8,mjob.jobId,mjob.jobReference)"
               class="dropdown-item text-warning"
               *ngIf="helper.right(userFunctionRights.jobs_Connote_Edit)">Change Status</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider" *ngIf="helper.right(userFunctionRights.jobs_Connote_Edit)"></div>

            <a role="button"
               (click)="onJobRemove(mjob.manifestItemId,mjob.jobReference,mjob.manifestId)"
               class="dropdown-item text-danger"
               *ngIf="helper.right(userFunctionRights.carrier_Manifest_Edit)">Remove Job</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider" *ngIf="helper.right(userFunctionRights.carrier_Manifest_Edit)"></div>

            <a [routerLink]="['/job', mjob.jobId, { type: jobType.Connote }]"
               class="dropdown-item font-size-8pt text-info" target="_blank">Open Connote</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>

            <a role="button"
               (click)="onJobPopupOpen(jobPropertyModalPopup,6,mjob.jobId,mjob.jobReference)"
               class="dropdown-item">Driver Tracking</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>

            <a role="button"
               (click)="onJobPopupOpen(jobPropertyModalPopup,1,mjob.jobId,mjob.jobReference)"
               class="dropdown-item text-success">Connote Actuals</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>

            <a role="button"
               (click)="onJobPopupOpen(jobPropertyModalPopup,7,mjob.jobId,mjob.jobReference)"
               class="dropdown-item text-info">Job Item Scan</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>

            <a role="button"
               (click)="onJobPopupOpen(jobPropertyModalPopup,2,mjob.jobId,mjob.jobReference)"
               class="dropdown-item">Connote Property</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>

            <a role="button"
               (click)="onJobPopupOpen(null,10,mjob.jobId,mjob.jobReference)"
               class="dropdown-item">Upload Documents</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="p-0 nowrap">       
        <span style="color: #B23CFD;">&nbsp;</span>
        <span title="{{getTripTypeStrV2(mjob.tripTypeId)}}" style="cursor:default;">{{getTripTypeStr(mjob.tripTypeId)}}</span>
        <span style="color: #B23CFD;">&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span>
        <span>{{mjob.jobReference}}</span>
        <span style="color: #B23CFD;">&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span>
        <span title="Pick-up Date">{{mjob.plannedPudateTime | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</span>
        <span style="color: #B23CFD;">&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span>
        <span title="Receiver Name">{{mjob.receiverName}}</span>
        <span style="color: #B23CFD;">&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span>
        <span title="Receiver Town">{{mjob.receiverTownName}}</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</ng-container>```
````

Comment: I can render 10000 of those icons pretty much instantly: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-q7fw3h?file=src/app/app.component.html. Try introducing other aspects of your project to see what is causing the problem. I see that some of your icons are different colors, how are you accomplishing that?

Comment: Hey Chris, Colours come from API as hex colours (like #fcba03). I have tried removing the colour but still the same.

Comment: There is nothing I can do without an URL.  I would need to run some tests.  My guess is the fonts are being loaded too late.  If the fonts are loaded while the page is rendering, the Browser stops and starts over again.